# Custom Taxation Logic Not Functioning on Token Contract - Previously Deployed Contract Exhibited Proper Functionality

Tags: erc-20, tokens, uniswap

I'm encountering an issue with the custom taxation logic implemented on my token contract. Interestingly, I've deployed a similar contract last year with the same logic, and it was functioning correctly. However, with the current contract, the taxation mechanism seems to be malfunctioning. I am testing the new token on seploia uniswap. Everything is working fine but only tax is not being deducted.  I've provided links to both contracts below:

Here is my current contract on sepolia: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x5eddce7a98ef07834f9ee3910f32e129590e1212

Previously Deployed Contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0xfdedd42a446bf6c5a883727cda6ff557511e3e1e

Could someone please help me understand why the taxation logic is not working as expected on the current token contract? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!